# Windows Phone 8 - change color in bitmap

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, image-processing, colors

How can I change one color of bitmap to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution uses `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods which are really slow. You can get the same result much faster working on pixels directly. But before that we have to know how to convert `Color` to int, because pixels in `WriteableBitmap` are represented by int array.

Some of my apps use this method to manipulate pixels and I wanted to do it as fast as possible, so never use `SetPixel` or `GetPixel` (eg. [MC Skin Editor](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mc-skin-editor/c1f26e5c-a4b7-4a25-8aa3-1514a594129f?signin=true), [MC Skin Viewer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mc-skin-viewer/5f9eea9b-cb9b-440f-a904-7df8bac59599)).

To convert `Color` to int I made this simple extension:

```
public static int ToInt(this Color color)
{
    return unchecked((int)((color.A << 24) | (color.R << 16) | (color.G << 8) | color.B));
}
```

So now, your method could look like this:

```
public static WriteableBitmap ChangeColor(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmapOriginal, Color originalColor, Color newColor)
{
    var writeableBitmapNew = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBitmapOriginal);
    originalColorInt = originalColor.ToInt();
    newColorInt = newColor.ToInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < writeableBitmapNew.Pixels.Length; i++)
        if (writeableBitmapNew.Pixels[i] == originalColorInt)
            writeableBitmapNew.Pixels[i] = newColorInt;
    return writeableBitmapNew;
}
```

Comment: Nice, too bad this answer was not on the internet when I was watching for it :).

Answer (score 0):

First, this is method which takes WritableBitmap a change color of your choice with another.

```
    public static WriteableBitmap ChangeColor(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmapOriginal, Color originalColor, Color newColor)
    {
        var writeableBitmapNew = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBitmapOriginal);

        for (int i = 0; i < writeableBitmapNew.PixelWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < writeableBitmapNew.PixelHeight; j++)
            {                    
                if (writeableBitmapOriginal.GetPixel(i, j).Equals(originalColor))
                {
                    writeableBitmapNew.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
                }
            }
        }
        return writeableBitmapNew;
    }
```

The imports for this method:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

I also add how to instantly use this method, because loading of BitmapImage can be quite annoying (it is not loaded instantly from URI, therefore you can easily get NullPointer exception, thats why I am using things like StreamResourceInfo)

```
Uri uri = new Uri("Assets/Icons/ic_black_star_fav.png", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(img);
WriteableBitmap newWbm = YourClassWithThisMethod.ChangeColor(wbm,Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
```

The code above load picture, and changes black non-transparent color into the red and put it into variable `newWbm`.

Comment: I don't recommend to use `SetPixel` method because it's slow. Better solution is to manipulate pixels directly.

Comment: I just added my solution in answer ;)